# Hide and Display menu Core UI

Tags: reactjs, core-ui

I integrated the template **`Core UI`** in my application.

The redirection is configured on **`_nav.js`** like presented by that picture:

[image]

I'm asking if it's possible to hide or display a menu depending on such condition ?.

For Exemple: Show `Public Student` and Hide `Manage Convention` depending on a condition.

[image]

The menu is defined on **_nav.js**

```
export default [
  {
    _tag: 'CSidebarNavTitle',
    _children: ['Menu'],
  },
  {
    _tag: 'CSidebarNavItem',
    name: 'Public Space',
    to: '/home',
  }, // ...
  {
    _tag: 'CSidebarNavItem',
    name: 'Manage Convention',
    to: '/manageConvention',
  }  // ...
]
```

Then, this Array is called on **TheSidebar.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { CCreateElement, CSidebar, CSidebarBrand, CSidebarNav, CSidebarNavDivider, CSidebarNavTitle, CSidebarMinimizer, CSidebarNavDropdown, CSidebarNavItem } from '@coreui/react'

import CIcon from '@coreui/icons-react'

// sidebar nav config
import navigation from './_nav'

const TheSidebar = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const show = useSelector(state => state.sidebarShow)

  return (
    <CSidebar
      show={show}
      onShowChange={(val) => dispatch({type: 'set', sidebarShow: val })}
    >
      <CSidebarBrand className="d-md-down-none" to="/">
        <CIcon
          className="c-sidebar-brand-full"
          name="logo-negative"
          height={35}
        />
        <CIcon
          className="c-sidebar-brand-minimized"
          name="sygnet"
          height={35}
        />
      </CSidebarBrand>
      <CSidebarNav>

        <CCreateElement
          items={navigation}
          components={{
            CSidebarNavDivider,
            CSidebarNavDropdown,
            CSidebarNavItem,
            CSidebarNavTitle
          }}
        />
      </CSidebarNav>
      <CSidebarMinimizer className="c-d-md-down-none"/>
    </CSidebar>
  )
}

export default React.memo(TheSidebar)
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated.Big Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean hiding/displaying Component based on a condition?
Asking because it seems pretty easy to do.

Comment: Hello Sir @Prashant Vishwakarma, thanks a lot for your reply. I added a screenshot to my question: I mean (for exemple) : **Show**  `Public Student` and **Hide** `Manage Convention`  _if the student is not authorized_. Have you please any idea about solving That ?. Big Thanks Sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a child component class `SidebarChild` in `TheSidebar.js` to precise the condition that you want.

Then, inject it in `<CSidebar >`.

and don't forget to use the constant `const SBChild = connect()(SidebarChild)` to be able to call `SBChild` inside `<CSidebar >`.

Hope To Help.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an old question but:

I think the simplest solution would be to add a **meta** prop inside `_nav.js` to every "**CNavItem**"

```
//_nav.js

const _nav = [    
       {
        component: CNavItem,
        name: 'Locations',
        to: '/location',
        meta: { role: ['Admin', 'Recruiter'] },
        icon: <CIcon icon={cilLocationPin} customClassName="nav-icon" />
      },
]
```

Helper function

```
export default function hasAccess(userRole, roles) {
    if (Array.isArray(userRole)) {
        return roles.some((r) => userRole.map((item) => item.toLowerCase()).includes(r.toLowerCase()))
    } else {
        return roles.map((item) => item.toLowerCase()).includes(userRole.toLowerCase())
    }
}
```

After, inside `AppSidebarNav.js` component, check if the nav item includes at least one of the user role. If it does, render it, otherwise no.

**userRole** it's returned from redux store in this case. It's up to you how you get the logged in user roles.

```
//AppSidebarNav.js

export const AppSidebarNav = ({ items }) => {
  const userRole = useSelector((state) => state.user.role)

  {...}

  const navItem = (item, index) => {
    const { component, name, badge, icon, meta, ...rest } = item
    const Component = component
    return (

      hasAccess(userRole, item.meta?.role || []) && <Component

        {...(rest.to &&
          !rest.items && {
          component: NavLink,
        })}
        key={index}
        {...rest}
      >
        {navLink(name, icon, badge)}
      </Component>
    )
  }
 
 
 {...}

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {items &&
        items.map((item, index) => (item.items ? (navGroup(item, index)) : navItem(item, index)))}
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading your comment, you can call an API to check for authorization (preferrably, just after login) and save it to state. You can use it as a flag as I've done below:

Try Changing the `true` on first line below to `false`.

```js
const getWorldAccess = () => true;//Call API for user access rights here and save it to a state

const World = () => <div>World</div>;

const Hello = () => {
    return (
      <div>Hello {getWorldAccess() && <World />}</div>
    );//replace getWorldAccess() with a state variable (you don't want to call API infinitely)
}

ReactDOM.render( <
  Hello / > ,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hello Sir  @Prashant Vishwakarma, thanks a lot for your reply, It seems that I didn't well explain my issue. So I added to my question `_nav.js` and `TheSidebar.js`. I'd like to `Show` **Public Student** menu always,  and `Hide` **Manage Convention** if the student have a mark less than 10 for exemple. Have you please any idea about solving That ?. Big Thanks Sir. –

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the `_nav.js` array within the `TheSideBar.js` according to the condition you want. That will hide it from displaying in sidebar. You will have to know what the index of the item you want to remove.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the best answer to your question.
First, you have to divide items in the _nav.js file according to the below structure. (This allows, to export the navbar items according to user levels).

```
import React from 'react'
import CIcon from '@coreui/icons-react'

var navStaff = { 
 items: [
    {
      _tag: 'CSidebarNavItem',
      name: 'Dashboard',
      to: '/dashboard',
      icon: <CIcon name="cil-speedometer" customClasses="c-sidebar-nav-icon"/>,
    }
 ]
};

var navAdmin = {
  items: [
    {
      _tag: 'CSidebarNavItem',
      name: 'Dashboard',
      to: '/dashboard',
      icon: <CIcon name="cil-speedometer" customClasses="c-sidebar-nav-icon"/>,
    },
    {
      _tag: 'CSidebarNavTitle',
      _children: ['USERS']
    },
    {
      _tag: 'CSidebarNavItem',
      name: 'Users',
      to: '/users',
      icon: 'cil-people',
    }
  ]
};

export {navStaff, navAdmin };
```

Then your TheSidebar.js should look like this which is used to allow different content in the navbar. If you want you can use the local storage to allow only the logged user type to allocate the selected navbar.

```
import React, { lazy, useState, useEffect, useRef} from 'react'
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import {
  CCreateElement,
  CSidebar,
  CSidebarBrand,
  CSidebarNav,
  CSidebarNavDivider,
  CSidebarNavTitle,
  CNavItem,
  CProgress,
  CSidebarMinimizer,
  CSidebarNavDropdown,
  CSidebarNavItem,
} from '@coreui/react'
import CIcon from '@coreui/icons-react'

// sidebar nav config
import {navStaff, navAdmin} from './_nav'

const TheSidebar = () => {

  console.log(navStaff)

  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const show = useSelector(state => state.sidebarShow);

  return (
    <CSidebar
      show={show}
      unfoldable
      onShowChange={(val) => dispatch({type: 'set', sidebarShow: val })}
    >
      <CSidebarBrand className="d-md-down-none" to="/">
        <CIcon
          className="c-sidebar-brand-minimized"
          name="sygnet"
          height={35}
        />
      </CSidebarBrand>
      <CSidebarNav>

        <CCreateElement
          items={navAdmin.items}
          components={{
            CSidebarNavDivider,
            CSidebarNavDropdown,
            CSidebarNavItem,
            CSidebarNavTitle
          }}
        />

        <CSidebarNavDivider />
      </CSidebarNav>
      <CSidebarMinimizer className="c-d-md-down-none"/>
    </CSidebar>
  )
}

export default React.memo(TheSidebar)
```

Hope you get the answer which you need. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

In the component, `CSidebar` just set value of `minimize` to true